# Dictionary finding similar value in different key

Tags: python, dictionary, compare

please help, i have a dictionary like this :

sdata = {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],'B': [11, 12, 3, 14, 15], 'C': [8, 9, 10, 1 ,2], 'D': [15, 3, 18, 19, 20]}

i want the output to be like:

Number of same digit in A and C : 2

number : 1, 2

number of same digit in B and D: 1

15

and also compare all 4 keys and return the number of unique digit.
which would be
17 unique number.

The following is my code:

```
keyAvalue = sdata.get('A')
    keyCvalue = sdata.get('C')
    keyBvalue= sdata.get('B')
    keyDvalue= sdata.get('D')
    countA= len(keyAvalue)
    countC= len(keyCvalue)
    compareAC = []
    compareBD= []
    for number in keyAvalue:
        if number in keyCvalue:
            if number not in compareAC:
                compareAC.append(number)
                countAC = len(compareAC)
    for number in keyBvalue:
        if number in keyDvalue:
            if number not in compareBD:
                compareBD.append(number)
                countBD = len(compareBD)
    for key, value in studentData.items():
        count = len([item for item in value if item]) #count number of values in key
        value.sort()
        formatValue = (" ".join(map(str,value)))
        formatAC = (" ".join(map(str,compareAC)))
        formatBD = (" ".join(map(str,compareBD)))   
 print (f'in both A and C = {countAC}\nnumber: {formatAC}\n')
    print (in both B and D = {countBD}\nnumber: {formatBD}\n')
    print (f'Number of unique number in A and C = {countA + countC - countAC}')
```

is there an easier way to do this? please help thank you in advance. By the way I'm not suppose to use set data type to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sdata = {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],'B': [11, 12, 3, 14, 15], 'C': [8, 9, 10, 1 ,2], 'D': [15, 3, 18, 19, 20]}

#going through the elements in sdata
for key in sdata.keys():
  #comparing every other list in sdata
  other_keys = [other for other in sdata.keys() if other != key]

  #checking the other list
  for other in other_keys:
    #the simliar count and value
    simliar = 0
    sim_vals = []
    #going through each value in the main list
    for value in sdata[key]:
      #checking if it is in the list
       if value in sdata[other]:
         simliar += 1
         sim_vals.append(value)

    print(other, key)
    #printing answer
    print(simliar)
    print(sim_vals)
```

Comment: This should work if i understood the problem correctly.

Comment: Hello, thank alot the code work but this code compare all the keys and value may i know how can i print only AC or BD?

Comment: You can just do a simple if loop when you are printing it.        For example you can do if key == A and other == C print.

Answer (score 0):

Finding common elements between two lists can be found using set.intersection().

suppose we have 2 lists:

```
list1 = [1, 2]
list2 = [1,3]
```

Convert list1 into set, so that we can perform intersect operation on it.

```
list1_as_set = set(list1)
intersection = list1_as_set.intersection(list2)
```

now convert this intersection into list again

```
intersection_as_list = list(intersection)
```

To print number of common elements in two list and its common elements:

```
print("Number of common elements in list1 and list2: {}".format(len(intersection_as_list)))
print("common elements in list1 and list2: {}".format(intersection_as_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from itertools import chain

def common_digits(l1, l2):
    return list(set(l1).intersection(l2))

def unique(l):
    return len(set(chain.from_iterable(l)))

sdata = {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],'B': [11, 12, 3, 14, 15], 'C': [8, 9, 10, 1 ,2], 'D': [15, 3, 18, 19, 20]}

print(common_digits(sdata['A'], sdata['C']))

print(common_digits(sdata['B'], sdata['D']))

print(unique(sdata.values()))
```